# Block-scoping in ES6 compiled by babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I know in es6 this is how to make a block scope.

```
'use strict';

{
    let account = [1678922, 300450];

    let compute = (credit, debit) => {
        return credit - debit;
    }

    console.log(compute(...account));
}
```

ES5 [this is what I expect]

```
(function(){
    var account = [1678922, 300450];

    var compute = function compute(credit, debit) {
        return credit - debit;
    };

    console.log(compute.apply(undefined, account));
})();

console.log(user1);
```

BABEL compiled

```
'use strict';

{
    var account = [1678922, 300450];

    var compute = function compute(credit, debit) {
        return credit - debit;
    };

    console.log(compute.apply(undefined, account));
}
```

I want to remove the global variable in compiled version.

Question:

1. Is there any way to do it without any plugin?
2. If no, is there a plugin using npm?

PS: I need to support ancient browser. Atleast IE9.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: add 'use strict'; above ur script?

Comment: can you give some context for this? i can think of a lot of ways around this: scope it to the function you are using, use an object literal to store it, etc., but it really depends on why you need it and how you're planning on using it.

Comment: @thesublimeobject, I believe the context given is clear. Why isnt the block scope working as intended.

Comment: @Mox I always put it. But I can access the variable outside the scope. :)

Comment: Your example output isn't what Babel outputs: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20user1%20%3D%20'user1'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(user1)%3B&stage=0 It doesn't need a function because Babel assume files will be modules, so a module loader would be responsible for wrapping each file in an IIFE.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping perhaps you may wanna use this

Comment: @loganfsmyth Actually, I just ran this exact code through webpack and babel-loader and it definitely is what it outputs. The thing is, I don't really see why this is a problem. I guess theoretically you have access to this variable post-compilation, but pre-compilation I would think babel would compile it in a way wherein if you have another variable named `user1`, the variables wouldn't collide on compilation; although, I need to actually run a test on that to see.

Comment: Yah, wait. I'll put the exact file. My point here is the block scoping of transpiled js.

Comment: Updated! Look at it sir. Thanks

Comment: It seems like the issue is what I mentioned above. In a standard Babel usecase, `var account` would not be a global, it would be scoped to a specific file by a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify. If you aren't using a module system, that would be the main issue to resolve ideally, or if you really want to be manually concatenating files, which is uncommon in modern JS, you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-iife-wrap.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks man! Finally, I got it now.

Comment: You are declaring let in global scope. So var is declared in global scope.

Comment: @DrEarnest It's the post compiled of ES6. Supporting ancient browser is difficult. But I already get the solution. :) Thanks for spending time with my question.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. Its not wrapping your expression in a function because you declared it in global scope using let. Isn't it so?

Comment: @DrEarnest you didn't get my question. I am running es6 + babel. So I compile it to ES5 to support older browser. So the script path is relative to the ES5 compiled version. Again, If I used the es6. There will be no problem since I wrapped them inside { }. { } == block scope and { } === ;(function(){ })();

Comment: @DrEarnest - No.  He declared the variables with `let` inside a block.  That is block scope, not global scope in Javascript ES6+ and the OP thinks babel should be cross compiling to ES5 code that respects and implements the block scope as in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Example from babel compilation; continuation from comments:

EDIT: BASED ON YOUR EXAMPLE

Precompiled:

```
{
    let account = [1678922, 300450];

    let compute = (credit, debit) => {
        return credit - debit;
    }

    console.log(compute(...account));
}

{
    let account = [16789, 3004];

    let compute = (credit, debit) => {
        return credit - debit;
    }

    console.log(compute(...account));
}
```

Postcompiled:

```
{
    var account = [1678922, 300450];

    var compute = function compute(credit, debit) {
        return credit - debit;
    };

    console.log(compute.apply(undefined, account));
}

{
    var _account = [16789, 3004];

    var _compute = function _compute(credit, debit) {
        return credit - debit;
    };

    console.log(_compute.apply(undefined, _account));
}
```

In essence, it doesn't matter. Babel is compiling it intelligently in a way that it doesn't matter, really.

Comment: No. Try to put my example into babeljs.io. I don't know why you get different result. I am using cli. And one more, it will be accessible in other script. Imagine if they can just type account or _account in console.

Comment: i'm not sure. i'm using compiling with webpack via babel-loader. given the module scope that it outputs, neither of those variables are available via global scope given that the file itself is exported via a function and required and called by webpack. i guess it could be a webpack specific thing, but they are not accessible to the global scope for me given the function wrapper.

Comment: As I said above, if you're not using a module bundler, which the babeljs.io website does not, you'll just get a global. Everyone uses bundlers these days though, so it's a non-issue.

Comment: Oh I see. I haven't tried to use module system. But I think in this project. I should learn it and it's a must. Thanks man for your time.